# Formatting error when removing values from a csv file and returning to a list

Tags: python, list, csv, formatting

I am reading a csv dataset and returning the X and Y coordinates to separate lists. I'm removing the XY Coordinates were the X-Coordinate is less than 5.

The csv is structured like this:

```
Frame   Time    Player 1_X  Player 1_Y  Player 2_X  Player 2_Y  Player 3_X   Player 3_Y
2920    15:31.0 67.30126517 23.99694962 3.753634891 -2.13857999 69.90505068 -2.504794226
2921    15:31.1 67.28604137 24.20629904 4.122542578 -1.939556384    69.83347832 -2.377951675
2922    15:31.2 67.27140091 24.41644649 4.500764877 -1.724636234    69.7662355  -2.257606667
2923    15:31.3 67.26373215 24.61751047 4.887649337 -1.501664655    69.72997973 -2.135141953
2924    15:31.4 67.28158751 24.80200421 5.294844117 -1.275928937    69.72595034 -2.013856015
2925    15:31.5 67.32005993 24.97498635 5.721823825 -1.042487504    69.73204207 -1.907299936
2926    15:31.6 67.36659395 25.14388582 6.155413991 -0.789898029    69.72947318 -1.811930399
2927    15:31.7 67.40717007 25.31477304 6.58302186  -0.513340546    69.71798806 -1.71190236
2928    15:31.8 67.42824027 25.48791173 7.001268674 -0.212791949    69.69067463 -1.61337704
2929    15:31.9 67.44179872 25.65540719 7.437058638 0.112079642 69.64537185 -1.526329851
2930    15:32.0 67.46336705 25.82181033 7.90386401  0.447834398 69.6061351  -1.441474747
```

I use the code below to remove all player's XY values were the X value is less than 5. So, using this code the XY data for Player 2 would be removed up to frame 2923.

```
with open('Wide_Single_timestamp2.csv') as csvfile :
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    n=0
    for row in readCSV :
        if n == 0 :
            n+=1            
            continue
        x_data = []
        y_data = []
        for (x,y) in [(2,3),(4,5),(6,7)]:
           xcoord = float(row[x])
           if xcoord >= 5:       
                x_data.append(xcoord)
                y_data.append(float(row[y]))
        visuals[1].append(x_data)
        visuals[0].append(y_data)
```

This works in the fact that the resulting data is removed from the X-Cordinates that are less than 5. However, I get a strange formatting result. Columns of empty data (those that were <5) are now filled with data from the right. Ex. Player 2 should be empty but it now has player 3's data (see below).

This is the export from the X columns. (The Y column is the same). As you can see, all data less than 5 are removed but the column to the right is shifted meaning it is not properly aligned with the appropriate player.

How do I keep the same structure of the dataset when removing values whilst reading from the file?

```
2920    67.27140091 69.7662355  
2921    67.26373215 69.72997973 
2922    67.28158751 5.294844117 69.72595034
2923    67.32005993 5.721823825 69.73204207
2924    67.36659395 6.155413991 69.72947318
2925    67.40717007 6.58302186  69.71798806
2926    67.42824027 7.001268674 69.69067463
2927    67.44179872 7.437058638 69.64537185
2928    67.46336705 7.90386401  69.6061351
```

The resulting dataset should look like:

```
2920    67.27140091             69.7662355  
2921    67.26373215             69.72997973 
2922    67.28158751 5.294844117 69.72595034
2923    67.32005993 5.721823825 69.73204207
2924    67.36659395 6.155413991 69.72947318
2925    67.40717007 6.58302186  69.71798806
2926    67.42824027 7.001268674 69.69067463
2927    67.44179872 7.437058638 69.64537185
2928    67.46336705 7.90386401  69.6061351
```

Were Player 3 is aligned with Player 3, not shifted to Player 2 when Player 2's data is removed. Sorry for the long-winded question. Just wanted to provide context. I don't understand why it formats this way or how I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up the entire row on the fly using by defining a function that returns the row with low values removed.  Also you can read in the header using `next()` on the reader object.

```
import csv

def clean_row(row, min_val=5, skip_left_cols=2):
    left = row[:skip_left_cols]
    right = [x if float(x)>min_val else '' for x in row[skip_left_cols]]
    return left+right

with open('Wide_Single_timestamp2.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    header = next(reader)
    data = [clean_row(row) for row in reader]
```

Comment: I get a `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'` on `right = [x if float(x)>min_val else '' for x in row[skip_left_cols]]`

Answer (score 0):

As discussed below, you need 2 lists. One with x coordinates of all players and one with y. Here is the code:

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('Wide_Single_timestamp2.csv')

x_list = []
y_list = []
for row in data.index:
  for player in ['Player 1', 'Player 2', 'Player 3']:
    x = data.loc[row, player + '_X']
    y = data.loc[row, player + '_Y']
    if x < 5:
      x = None
      y = None
    if x:
      x_list.append(x)
    if y:
      y_list.append(y)
```

Comment: I'm aware of pandas. I don't want to replace with null. I can load a dataset with null values. I need the csv to be read which removes the X and Y Coordinate data where the X-Coordinate is less than 5. Without losing the data structure.

Comment: Hi @JeremyAlexander, just to clarify your need, you want to remove the X and Y values (not the record), where X<5. But you don’t want the X and Y values to be replaced by null or NaN. You want the coordinates to be empty instead like this for instance ‘’. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @JeremyAlexander I have updated my answer above. Let me know if that corresponds to what you need?

Comment: Sorry, I din't provide enough info at the start. I need to read a csv and return the data to a list to be used for a later function. I have tried your process and the missing data can't be used as it returns and error. See question

Comment: Hi @JeremyAlexander, So you want the output of your process to be a list and each item in the list should contain values from the following columns: ['Frame', 'Player 1_X', 'Player 2_X', 'Player 3_X'] (so basically you would have a list of lists). Is this correct?

Comment: Not quite. Each list would contain y data or x data `x_data = []`. It has to be done upon reading the csv file. I need to read through the file and only return appropriate values to that list.

Comment: Ok, using panda it is possible to convert each column into a list. Example `x_data = data['Player 1_X'].values.tolist()` does that answer your question?

Comment: @JeremyAlexander, I've updated the answer above to add how to output each column of the panda dataframe into a list. Let me know.

Comment: No, there's a breakdown here. I can perform these functions. It needs to be when reading the file. I can return values to a `df` or a `list []`. But when I go to read that `df` or `list []` I'll get the same `Type Error` because there is data missing. So the undesired data has to be removed upon reading the csv file. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JeremyAlexander I'm sorry it does not make sense to me in regards to the initial question. If what you need is to have 2 separate lists (one with the x coordinates, one with the y), there is no such thing as keeping the structure of the data set. The print of your final data set is very misleading. Can you please adjust that?

Comment: @JeremyAlexander I have update my answer above. Is it what you want?

Comment: I've tried it. Not sure how long it should take but I've stopped it after 30 mins. The data is fine. I can read it but when I execute the code it doesn't work.

Comment: @JeremyAlexander how big is your file? It's looping over every record so if you have thousands (millions?) it might take some time... Can you try with a small version of your file at least to make sure the code is working?

Comment: @JeremyAlexander can you try the other solution below and let me know if performances are better.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer which might be better in terms of performances because it does not loop over all records of all player columns.

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('Wide_Single_timestamp2.csv')

data.loc[data['Player 1_X'] < 5, ['Player 1_X', 'Player 1_Y']] = 'nd', 'nd'
data.loc[data['Player 2_X'] < 5, ['Player 2_X', 'Player 2_Y']] = 'nd', 'nd'
data.loc[data['Player 3_X'] < 5, ['Player 3_X', 'Player 3_Y']] = 'nd', 'nd'

x_list = data['Player 1_X'].values.tolist() + data['Player 2_X'].values.tolist() + data['Player 3_X'].values.tolist()
list(filter(('nd').__ne__, x_list))

y_list = data['Player 1_Y'].values.tolist() + data['Player 2_Y'].values.tolist() + data['Player 3_Y'].values.tolist()
list(filter(('nd').__ne__, y_list))
```